# Meteor not passing error to client

Tags: javascript, mysql, meteor, reactjs

I'm writing an integration with our website with a service backed by MySQL. I had some problems with async functions but I managed to fix them eventually. Now lastly I want to throw an error when a game has not yet finished to the user.

```
//server method
getGameScore(variable) {    
connection.query(sql, Meteor.bindEnvironment((err, rows) => {
if (err) throw err;
  if (parseInt(rows[0].status, 10) === 13) {
  // a whole lot of code wchich works just fine
  } else {
    throw new Meteor.Error('The match has not finished yet');
  }
}));
},

'ebot.getGameScore'(variable) {
check(variable, String);

return Meteor.server.ebot.getScore(variable);
},
```

And my client side code. The error is showing in my server console but when console logging my err or result both are undefined. I think it has something to do with asynchronous execution of the code.

```
getMySQLScore() {
  Meteor.call('ebot.getGameScore', this.props.match._id, (err, result) => {        
    if (err) {
      toastr.error(err.message);
    }
  });
},
```

Anyone with an idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: I think the bind environment is causing your issue here, I'm fairly sure it runs on a separate fibre which I'd why the error is not being thrown on return to the client. If you return the error not throw it inside getScore and rethrow it outside the bind you could confirm this or declare a has_error flag at top of func, set it to the error and check it before returning the output of getScore

Comment: The problem is if I set a variable hasErrors outside my bindEnvironment and I set this to true. then I throw the error outside the bindEnvironment. The problem is that this also happens asynchronous so the hasErrors variable is not set yet so the error is not thrown.